How do I link a Gradio Button to a File button?
I'm trying to make a gr.Button() activate a gr.File(). I tried linking the inputs/outputs but it doesn't work. Here's what I have:
import gradio as gr

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    with gr.Column():
        smaller_button = gr.Button(value='Shortcut (this button is supposed to activate the other one)')
        select_directory_button = gr.File(label='Linked Button (do not click)')

    # smaller_button.click(inputs=smaller_button, outputs=[select_directory_button])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.launch()

Visually, it looks like this:

